# Is it possible to view the current file content during directory navigation in vi (command line, not GUI)?

Tags: netrw

(Originally asked in a wrong place - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780235/is-it-possible-to-view-the-current-file-content-during-directory-navigation-in-v)

I am watching [this Pluralsight course on helm](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/kubernetes-packaging-applications-helm/table-of-contents) and the instructor uses vi from the linux console all the time in the **directory browsing mode** with the current file being automatically open for viewing in the other pane:
[image]

When I run `vi .` it does open the directory navigation mode, but I have only one pane and to view a file I need to Enter it and then it shows it **instead** of the directory view. I can go back with `:E`, but the experience is not the same.

How can we tell vi to automatically open the current file in a side pane, so both the directory navigator and the file content are available in side by side panes?

I do not have any vi configuration. This is a fresh new Linux 18.04 VM to which I connect with ssh.

Comment: Not an answer, but you might want to give this a read: [Article on project drawers](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/)

Comment: @JakeGrossman the command is `vi .` (edit the current directory), which automatically opens netrw. It appears that while hovering in netrw, they get a side-panel with the file.

Comment: I used `vi .`. I do not understand the meaning of "hovering" when working from the console. What I can see is that in the console mode there is no hovering. I can move the selection from file to file and enter folders. But to view a file I need to enter it and that opens the file content instead of the file browser. In short, the default out of the box experience is not the one I wish to have, The accepted answer moves me closer to the desired experience.

Comment: By hovering I meant using the cursor the “hover” (be on top of) a file in netrw. You said automatically, so I assumed no extra action was taken by the instructor. If they pressed v or p the screenshot would actually make more sense to me. I agree that out of box =/= what you described.

Comment: It could be the instructor presses something. For now I assume he presses `p` as indicated by the answer. I find it quite confusing - Enter to enter a folder, but `p` to preview. I find myself often pressing Enter instead of `p` and then I have no idea how to return back to the file navigator - has to quit vi completely and restart.

Comment: You may like `:Rexplore` (Rex for short). Try pressing F1 in netrw, or reading it’s help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Originally answered on Stack Overflow.)

This is using the [`:Lexplore`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-%3ALexplore) mode of netrw.

Either open it with `:Lexplore` from inside Vim, or if you want to start Vim with it open, use `vim +Lexplore` (instead of `vim .`), or `vim +Lex` for short.

---

If you prefer to use the "preview" feature, to open the file in the right window while keeping the cursor on the netrw window, then set the following variable:

```
" Open the preview window vertically.
let g:netrw_preview = 1
```

Then open netrw by itself with `vim .` or `:e .` and then use the `p` key to open the file in a "preview" window. The first time you use `p` will open the preview window.

You might want to also set:

```
let g:netrw_preview   = 1
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_winsize   = 30
```

See [`:help netrw-preview`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-preview) for details.

Comment: What I still do not understand is when I Enter the file and the focus shifts to the other pane - how do I return back to the directory navigator pane? Right now I run the `q` command to close the file editor pane. I am still to try the preview commands.

Comment: Can I add +Lexplore to ~/.vimrc ? I tried adding `Lexplore` and `+Lexplore` and `:Lexplore`, but none is working. I know I need to RTFM, so if you point me in the right direction I guess I would manage.

Comment: @mark The vimrc file is loaded very early, before plug-ins. You need an autocmd instead, for that. This should work: `autocmd VimEnter * Lexplore`